# I want to read a file of structs and it would not be reading correctly

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
typedef struct 
{
  int Id_provincia;
  struct fec{
      int dd;
      int mm;
      int aa;
  }Fecha;
  char Tipo_alerta;
}incendio;


int main(){
    int Num;
    FILE *archivo;
    archivo = fopen("Incendios_carga.dat", "rb");
    if (archivo == NULL){
        exit(1);
    }

    incendio foco;
    fread(&foco, sizeof(incendio), 1, archivo);
    while(!feof(archivo)){
        printf("el ID_Proviconcia es: : %d \n",foco.Id_provincia);
        fread(&foco, sizeof(incendio), 1, archivo);
        Num++;
    }
    printf("la cantidad de regs son:%d",Num);
    fclose(archivo);
}
```

this program should show on the screen the Id_Province that are 22 and it does not do that it shows random numbers I don't know why.
The file that I am opening comes from another program with which I load the information to the file to process it with this program

Comment: How was the file you read from created? What was actually written to it?

Comment: Note that [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)!

Comment: Also, note that `Num` is never initialized, so you will get indeterminate (quasi-random) values in it

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, note that this particular code happens to rescue the `while(!feof(archivo))` by hoisting one `fread()` out of the loop.  Not that I think that's good style, but it's not semantically wrong.

Comment: @JohnBollinger — yes, I noticed that the "always" in "always wrong" wasn't "completely accurate".  However, it does involve unnecessary code repetition.  The loop should be `while (fread(&foco, sizeof(incendio), 1, archive) == 1)` without any other call to `fread()` around.  And then you don't need to check `feof()` either.

Answer (score 0):

Your primary problem is that you do not initialize `Num` to zero, so you get indeterminate (quasi-random) starting points for your counting.

You also have unnecessary includes, use `feof()` unnecessarily, and have unnecessary code repetition because of that.  (See also the discussion in the comments to the question.)

Your code should be more like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct 
{
    int Id_provincia;
    struct fec
    {
        int dd;
        int mm;
        int aa;
    } Fecha;
    char Tipo_alerta;
} incendio;

int main(void)
{
    const char filename[] = "Incendios_carga.dat";
    FILE *archivo = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (archivo == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to open file '%s' for reading\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }

    incendio foco;
    int Num = 0;
    while (fread(&foco, sizeof(foco), 1, archive) == 1)
    {
        printf("el ID_Proviconcia es: %d\n", foco.Id_provincia);
        Num++;
    }
    printf("la cantidad de regs son: %d\n", Num);
    fclose(archive);
    return 0;
}
```

The [placement of braces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) is subjective — you can use 1TBS, but I prefer Allman.  Just be consistent (and you were almost entirely consistent — the `{` after the `typedef` is on the wrong line for 00% consistency).

Print messages with a trailing newline.  Print errors on `stderr`, not `stdout`.  Avoid exiting a program silently when an error occurs.  Report the name of the file that can't be opened.  That usually means "use a variable (or `#define`) to hold the filename so you can pass it to both `fopen()` and `fprintf()`".  IMO, it is rarely correct to call `fopen()` or any other file-opening function with a string literal for the file name because you need to repeat the string in the error message.  Since you defined variable `foco` just before the loop, I move the definition of `Num` there too, initializing it to zero.  I prefer programs to finish with `return 0;` even though C99 says it isn't necessary.  (I regard that as a bug in the standard, but it was done for conformity with C++98.  I just don't use the (mis-)feature.)